# Attempt to read property when calling a class

Tags: php, phpmailer

i am getting this error when i call my phpMailer class

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "email" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\WiShop\core\controllers\admin.php on line 254
```

and this is my line 254

```
                $result = $email -> send_email_admin_cancel_order($client_info[0] -> full_name, $client_info -> email, $_GET['code']);
```

and this is class call on line 253

```
                $email = new sendEmail;
```

and i don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to use `->` syntax on an array; this only works on objects.

`$client_info` is currently an array not an object. I assume this only happens with the `email` property and not `full_name` because you are not taking the `i`th item when accessing `email`, e.g.

`$client_info[0]->full_name`
`$client_info->email`
Based on context you need to change the second line to `$client_info[0]->email`.